# Converting a Google Apps Script to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

I guess this will seem a bit lazy, but I have been working on this for quite a few hours to get it to work in Google Sheets. Now I have the need to also get it to work in Excel, using VBA. It's a pretty simple script for experienced programmers, which I am not. :-)

I have a range of letters in a spreadsheet. Each letter represent a value. The Google Apps Script looks like this:

```
function Arsarbetstid(v,year) {
  switch(year) {

    case 2020:    // Tider gällande 2020
      var n=6.7,  // N
          np=9,   // N+
          k=8.8,  // K
          km=7,   // K-
          k4=4,   // K4
          d=8.8,  // D
          h=12,   // H
          hp=13;  // H+
      break;

    case 2019:    // Tider gällande 2019
      var n=6.9,  // N
          np=9,   // N+
          k=8.7,  // K
          km=7,   // K-
          k4=4,   // K4
          d=9,    // D
          h=12,   // H
          hp=13;  // H+
      break;

    case 2018:    // Tider gällande 2018
      var n=6.9,  // N
          np=9,   // N+
          k=8.7,  // K
          km=7,   // K-
          k4=4,   // K4
          d=9,    // D
          h=12,   // H
          hp=13;  // H+
      break;

    case 2017:    // Tider gällande 2017
      var n=7,    // N
          np=9,   // N+
          k=8.8,  // K
          km=7,   // K-
          k4=4,   // K4
          d=9.1,  // D
          h=12,   // H
          hp=13;  // H+
      break;

    case 2016:    // Tider gällande 2016
      var n=7,    // N
          np=9,   // N+
          k=8.8,  // K
          km=7,   // K-
          k4=4,   // K4
          d=9.1,  // D
          h=12,   // H
          hp=13;  // H+
      break;

    case 2015:    // Tider gällande 2015
      var n=7,    // N
          np=9,   // N+
          k=8.8,  // K
          km=7,   // K-
          k4=4,   // K4
          d=9.1,  // D
          h=12,   // H
          hp=13;  // H+
      break;

    case 2014:    // Tider gällande 2014
      var n=7,    // N
          np=9,   // N+
          k=8.8,  // K
          km=7,   // K-
          k4=4,   // K4
          d=9.1,  // D
          h=12,   // H
          hp=13;  // H+
      break;

    case 2013:    // Tider gällande 2013
      var n=7,    // N
          np=9,   // N+
          k=8.8,  // K
          km=7,   // K-
          k4=4,   // K4
          d=9.1,  // D
          h=12,   // H
          hp=13;  // H+
      break;

    default:      // Tider gällande om inget årtal anges.
      var n=6.7,  // N
          np=9,   // N+
          k=8.8,  // K
          km=7,   // K-
          k4=4,   // K4
          d=8.8,  // D
          h=12,   // H
          hp=13;  // H+
      break;   

  }

  var total = 0;
  for (var i=0;i < v.length;i++) {
    var row = v[i];
    for (var j=0;j < row.length;j++) {
       switch(row[j]) {
         case "N":
           total += n;
           break;
         case "N+":
           total += np;
           break;
         case "D":
           total += d;
           break;
         case "H":
           total += h;
           break;
         case "H+":
           total += hp;
           break;
         case "K":
           total += k;
           break;
         case "K-":
           total += km;
           break;
         case "K4":
           total += k4;
           break;
                  }
    }
  }

  return total;
};
```

v is the range of letters and year is just an integer representing a year so I can chose different values of the letters depending of the year.
I have tried, and so far failed, to convert this to VBscript. Is there anyone out there skilled enough to help me convert this? It shouldn't be too hard to anyone with at least a little above basic skills in both Javascript and VBscript.

The VBA so far looks like this, but doesn't work.

```
Public Function arsarbetstid(v As Range, year As Integer)
Dim total As Double
    Select Case year
        Case 2020
            n = 6.7
            np = 9
            k = 8.8
            km = 7
            k4 = 4
            d = 8.8
            h = 12
            hp = 13
        Case 2019
            n = 6.7
            np = 9
            k = 8.8
            km = 7
            k4 = 4
            d = 8.8
            h = 12
            hp = 13
        Case 2018
            n = 6.7
            np = 9
            k = 8.8
            km = 7
            k4 = 4
            d = 8.8
            h = 12
            hp = 13
        Case 2017
            n = 6.7
            np = 9
            k = 8.8
            km = 7
            k4 = 4
            d = 8.8
            h = 12
            hp = 13
        Case 2016
            n = 6.7
            np = 9
            k = 8.8
            km = 7
            k4 = 4
            d = 8.8
            h = 12
            hp = 13
        Case 2015
            n = 6.7
            np = 9
            k = 8.8
            km = 7
            k4 = 4
            d = 8.8
            h = 12
            hp = 13
        Case 2014
            n = 6.7
            np = 9
            k = 8.8
            km = 7
            k4 = 4
            d = 8.8
            h = 12
            hp = 13
        Case 2013
            n = 6.7
            np = 9
            k = 8.8
            km = 7
            k4 = 4
            d = 8.8
            h = 12
            hp = 13
        Case Else
            n = 6.7
            np = 9
            k = 8.8
            km = 7
            k4 = 4
            d = 8.8
            h = 12
            hp = 13
    End Select
    For i = 0 To v.Length
        Row = v(i)
        For j = 0 To Row.Length
        Select Case Row(j)
            Case "N"
                total = total + n
            Case "N+"
                total = total + np
            Case "D"
                total = total + d
            Case "H"
                total = total + h
            Case "H+"
                total = total + hp
            Case "K"
                total = total + k
            Case "K-"
                total = total + km
            Case "K4"
                total = total + k4
            End Select
        Next
    Next
    arsarbetstid = total
End Function
```

I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: VBA has `Select Case` instead of `switch`  - that and For...Next loops are all you need.

Comment: Thanks Tim!

I am aware of that, and I have tried to adapt the code for that, but I still does not succeed in converting it. I have also changed the For...Next loops for VB script.

Comment: So... you might consider posting the current form of your attempt at conversion, and explain what is the problem you're having with it.  That's typically all folks are looking for here.

Comment: Of course. I didn't think of it at first, but now my original post is edited. Thanks for you reply!

Comment: I would like to use something like this in a cell: =arsarbetstid(C5:I57;2019)
and at the moment I get only #VALUE! in the cell.

Comment: @michael-rodin Please stop calling VBA in Excel VBScript, they are different.

Comment: @Lankymart I am sorry for that. My total lack of scripting experience in Excel made me do it. Lesson learned!

Comment: @michael-rodin no problem, I've edited the tags for you.

Answer (score 0):

The last part would be something like this:

```
For Each c In v.Cells
    Select Case c.Value
        Case "N": total = total + n
        Case "N+": total = total + np
        'etc

    End Select
Next c
```

When trying to debug a UDF it's easier to call it from a Sub:

```
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print arsarbetstid(Range("C5:I57"), 2019)
End sub
```

Then you can see what the problem is instead of just getting #VALUE!

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim! It still doesn't work, but how do I call the Tester routine?

Comment: In the editor place your cursor in the sub and hit F5

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention! I finally got it to work.

Comment: Good to hear you got it figured out.